# Sigabrt on glTexImage2D

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, freetype2

My code was in a working state when I left for the weekend and since I came back I have been randomly getting this error. Sometimes it runs and my android project works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm currently working on NDK and trying to get Freetype Lib to work. From reading this stack trace out here is my "relevant" code:

```
void TextRenderer::SetupGlyphs(std::string fontPath, int size){
    if(shadersInitialized == 0)
        CreateShader();
    glUseProgram(this->shader);

    // FreeType
    FT_Library ft;
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "SetupGlyphs", "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library.");

    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, fontPath.c_str(), 0, &face))
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "SetupGlyphs", "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font: %s", fontPath.c_str());

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, size);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++){
        if(FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)){
            printf("ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load Glyph\n");
            continue;
        }
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(
                GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                GL_RGB,
                face->glyph->bitmap.width,
                face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
                0,
                GL_RGB,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
        );
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        Character character = {
                texture,
                ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
                ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
                static_cast<GLuint>(face->glyph->advance.x)
        };
        characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
}
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
7-05 08:38:23.956 3055-3068/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3068 (GLThread 131)
07-05 08:38:24.059 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-05 08:38:24.059 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:6.0/MASTER/2872745:userdebug/test-keys'
07-05 08:38:24.059 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
07-05 08:38:24.059 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86_64'
07-05 08:38:24.059 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG: pid: 3055, tid: 3068, name: GLThread 131  >>> com.example.SanAngeles <<<
07-05 08:38:24.059 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
07-05 08:38:24.062 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     rax 0000000000000000  rbx 00007fd760fbd500  rcx ffffffffffffffff  rdx 0000000000000006
07-05 08:38:24.062 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     rsi 0000000000000bfc  rdi 0000000000000bef
07-05 08:38:24.062 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     r8  0000000000000012  r9  0000000000000003  r10 0000000000000008  r11 0000000000000202
07-05 08:38:24.063 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     r12 0000000000000bfc  r13 0000000000000006  r14 00007fd75d53fb00  r15 000000000000002c
07-05 08:38:24.063 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
07-05 08:38:24.063 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     rip 00007fd769f3f547  rbp 000000000000000e  rsp 00007fd760fbca38  eflags 0000000000000202
07-05 08:38:24.064 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
07-05 08:38:24.064 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000087547  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+7)
07-05 08:38:24.064 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000085b11  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+65)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000002e841  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+17)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000000288fd  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+61)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000002671  /system/lib64/libOpenglSystemCommon.so (QemuPipeStream::writeFully(void const*, unsigned long)+129)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000000000017c86  /system/lib64/libGLESv2_enc.so
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000000e47f  /system/lib64/libGLESv2_enc.so (GL2Encoder::s_glTexImage2D(void*, unsigned int, int, int, int, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*)+159)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000000c5ee  /system/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so (glTexImage2D+94)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00000000000cfb84  /data/app/com.example.SanAngeles-1/lib/x86_64/libsanangeles.so (TextRenderer::SetupGlyphs(std::string, int)+510)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00000000000cfef9  /data/app/com.example.SanAngeles-1/lib/x86_64/libsanangeles.so (TextRenderer::TextRenderer(std::string, std::vector<ProjectLabel, std::allocator<ProjectLabel> >, int)+173)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000000cb61a  /data/app/com.example.SanAngeles-1/lib/x86_64/libsanangeles.so (appInit+1144)
07-05 08:38:24.065 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00000000000ceb49  /data/app/com.example.SanAngeles-1/lib/x86_64/libsanangeles.so (Java_com_example_SanAngeles_DemoRenderer_nativeInit+78)
07-05 08:38:24.066 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000030e080  /data/app/com.example.SanAngeles-1/oat/x86_64/base.odex (offset 0x1d0000) (void com.example.SanAngeles.DemoRenderer.nativeInit(java.lang.String)+180)
07-05 08:38:24.066 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 000000000030e5f3  /data/app/com.example.SanAngeles-1/oat/x86_64/base.odex (offset 0x1d0000) (void com.example.SanAngeles.DemoRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig)+423)
07-05 08:38:24.066 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0000000073ee31f8  /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1ed6000)
07-05 08:38:24.127 1193-1193/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_05
07-05 08:38:24.127 1193-1193/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe## Heading ##
```

Why does it only sometimes fail?

Edit: Through logging I have found that it fails at character with ascii code 35.

Edit2: I have no idea why, but it randomly gets stuck on different characters. Sometimes, even, it won't get stuck at all and will just compile and run... I don't even know anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to anyone that may find this post, scowering the web for hours on end, I found the answer. Freetype is not aligned (at least not in my project) through `GL_RGB`, instead is aligned through `GL_LUMINANCE`. By changing such things in `glTexImage2D` I solved on the above issues, as well as some funky graphics errors I was getting.

TLDR;

```
glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RGB,                        => GL_LUMINANCE
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_RGB,                        => GL_LUMINANCE
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
    );
```

Comment: In general freetype is not bound to GL_LUMINANCE format, there could be differend pixel types (including 1-bit or palette colors). You should check your face->glyph->bitmap.palette_mode (must be 0) and face->glyph->bitmap.num_grays (must be 256). Also I suggest not using face->glyph->bitmap.width while uploading a texture, you should use face->glyph->bitmap.pitch instead (in most cases they are equal but in general they are not).